# Algorithm for this sequence in python function

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Write a function named q1() that accepts one (1) parameter, a String which you can assume will always
contain a sequence of only digits and should evaluate the String as if it loops around infinitely end-to-end.
The purpose of the q1() function is to verify that for every digit n in the String, there are never
more than n other digits in between recurring values. (i.e., there are no more than two digits between
each occurrence of 2, three digits between each 3, four digits between each 4, etc..) If this is the case,
the function should return `True`, otherwise it should return `False`.

For example, consider the String: '32423'
The first digit is 3, and there are only three other values in between the occurrences of the digit 3. The
second digit is 2, and are there are never more than two other values in between occurrences of the digit 2.
The third digit is 4; it isn’t duplicated.  However if you view the String as looping infinitely, you will find that
only four other values are passed before looping back to the digit 4 again.

For this example, the q1()
function would return `True`

```
def q1(nostring):
for i in range(len(nostring)):
    count=0
    for j in range(i+1,len(nostring)):
        if nostring[i]!=nostring[j]:
            count+=1
        else:
            break
    if count > eval(nostring[i]):
        return False
else:
    return True
```

This code gives fine output in every test case except '235234'
It should return False
It gives out True instead

I came up with this so far and it doesn't work
I have been having a really hard time figuring the out how to make it work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In particular, "it doesn't work" is not a problem specification.  Since you haven't included the problem statement (off-site links aren't proper documentation), a test case, the output you expected, and what you *did* get, it's hard to help you.

Comment: there's an else without an if statement to start....

Comment: @0TTT0: Those are attached to the `for` statements. They're syntactically valid (though they may not be *correct*).

Comment: @Prune is it fine now?

Comment: @dummy: Not yet.  Check the list I gave you.

Comment: @Prune Idk what i am doing wrong

Comment: Please add a specific question. Letting us know if the for...else is on purpose, (or if there are indentation problems), is helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems with this.

Your main problem is in your logic: you've counted in both directions and *totaled* the gap between the two numbers.  For instance, with the string `1918171`, you count a gap of 1 going forward, another gap of 1 coming back, and accumulate the two: 2>1, so you report failure.

Second, an `else` after a `for` is not used that often, and I think you haven't quite understood how they work.  I don't think they work the way you want.  Put in a few simple, tracing `print` statements to dump values and follow what *does* happen when you run the code.  You have a lot of things correct, but you should test each individual block of code before you add the next (incremental programming).

Comment: I got it at last!